# Convert a RGBA bytearray into a cv2 image (no errors, cv2 hang forever)

Tags: python, image, opencv

I receive from websocket an array of `[r, g, b, a ... r, g, b, a]` representing a 300x300 image

```py
img = np.asarray( bytearray(data), dtype=np.uint8 ).reshape( 300, 300, 4 )
```

I convert this image using numpy and get an array of array `[[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a]]`

I want to convert that `npArray` into a cv2 image. I try everything but nothing work. The code hang without errors ...

```py
img = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow('frame', img)
```

I don't understand what I should do and/or it hangs for any other reason...

Comment: Could you add your data array?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: what is the meaning of `img = cv2.imread(img`, did you try to read image from the numpy array?

Comment: "I want to convert that npArray into a cv2 image." -- OpenCV in Python using numpy arrays to represent images. | `cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` -- according to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.9/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) the first parameter of this function is a **filename**.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you don't need to.

When you use `cv2.imread()` it reads and decodes a JPEG-encoded, or PNG-encoded image (or TIFF or other) from disk. It does **decoding of compressed** images. Your image is not compressed so you don't need that.

Internally, OpenCV stores images as Numpy arrays - you already have that, so your array is already an image. Happy days! You don't need to do anything, this is enough:

```
img = np.asarray( bytearray(data), dtype=np.uint8 ).reshape( 300, 300, 4 )
```

Note that `np.asarray()` shares its data with the `bytearray` so you may have trouble altering the image. If so, you can make your own modifiable copy with:

```
img = np.array(... as above ...)
```

Note also that `cv2.imshow()` requires a `waitKey()` afterwards to update the display:

```
cv2.imshow("Window Title", image)
cv2.waitKey(-1)
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, the array comes from websocket (so it should be dublicated), the app is alive so I should not need waitKey(-1) Should it work even if I have 4 values: rgba instead of 3: rgb ?

Comment: You only need the `cv2.waitKey()` if you have `cv2.imshow()`

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with the image but `cv2.imshow()` is useless with alpha channels, so you may want to drop the transparency `RGB=image[...,:3]`